# What option to select when cloning Git project in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have cloned `Gradle` project from `GitHub` in `IntelliJ` and then got the following dialog:

[image]

Should I select "existing sources" because my sources exist and not external, or should I select "external model" because it has `Gradle` specification?

Answer (score 0):

You should choose Gradle becouse only this way the IDE will properly find and use build.gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose *external model*. You want IntelliJ to look at your Gradle file and decide how to set itself up based on what is in your Gradle file.

You use the *existing sources* option when you don't have Gradle file or Maven pom and you need IntelliJ to look at the sources and figure out what to do without a file to guide it.

There is some documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-a-project-by-importing-existing-sources.html